Adding additional information to the ethereum uri scheme just like BIP 0021
I have a use case where i want to generate qr code using which the users will pay me.
But i do not have way to recognize transaction.
Using Blockchain URI scheme we can add additional parameters like label and message.
Is there a way to add additional parameters in ethereum uri. I am not able to find any useful resource. They say discussions are are currently ongoing.
